# Can Select.... for Update lock the row from other Selects?

Tags: oracle

I have seen a lot places mention that Oracle

```
Select...For Update;
```

will prevent other transaction from `UPDATING` current row, in terms of lock those selected rows.

However I wonder if there is any chance that this query can use like prevent other transaction to `SELECT` this row as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  In Oracle, readers do not block writers and writers do not block readers.  Updating a row (or locking it in preparation for updating it) cannot block a pure reader.  Actually updating the row may slow down queries which may have to apply `UNDO` in order to get back the version of the block that they need to read but it won't block the reader.